# Bosch Nyon and W-LAN

Tags: electric-bike, electronics

I have an electric bike with a Bosch engine (Performance Line) and a Nyon Computer.

The Nyon is not able to connect to WPA or WPA2 password protected networks. If I remove authentication on my network I am then able to connect (and was able to update the device).

As Bosch does not give any way to communicate with them (support is only through the dealer which I doubt will be able to help) I am trying here (if there a is more technical forum or exchange site please tell me)

Now the question:

Is it possible to connect to a password protected WiFi Network (as stated in the manual) or is there a known bug?

**Edit**

With the latest update (August 2015) WPA2 seems to work. 802.11X is still completely broken (the Nyon does not even see/show the Network SSID)

Comment: Look for a hard port like a usb or micro usb.

Comment: It has a USB port but there are no application (other than for dealers) to do something with it ... The computer does not recognise the device.

Comment: Welcome to [Bicycles.SE] @Matteo. This doesn't really seem to be a bike question, more of a networking question. Good luck with it :-)

Comment: @andy256: I don't agreee. It about a bicycle part. Nowadays electronics are an important part of the bicycle word. Why is there an electronics tag then?

Comment: @Matteo If I thought your question was off topic I'd have said so. I'm saying good luck. I'm interested to see if anyone has any actual experience to give, or just suggestions. Again, I think a site like http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ might be an alternative If you don't get a solution here. Check their help before posting.

Comment: @andy256 I can try but the chance that someone (other then an ebike enthusiast) has the device is in my opinion 0 ... On bicycles.stackexchange there is the right user pool: cyclists. Not all of the would be interested in electronic devices but the same applies for mountain bikes (not all the user care about them)

Comment: That doesn't look like a nice way of doing business.  I'd contact them on the form anyway even though it's not meant for end users, you haven't got anything to lose.

Comment: @ChrisH I agree with you but there is no form. Just a text telling you to contact the reseller... Otherwise I would have tried :-)

Comment: Googling "nyon bike computer" in English took me to an English but.de website with contact forms for dealers etc. I'm on my phone now but can send the link if you can't find it (maybe the language Google wants to give you). Also the bike manufacturer (bosch say that's not them) may help - but only by passing your enquiry to bosch.

Comment: @Matteo back on the PC now so here you go: http://www.bosch-ebike.de/en/service/contact/contactform.php (you need to disable noscript to see the forms)

Comment: After a comment on Facebook I got a contact e-mail: contact@bosch-ebike.com. They quickly answered: no problem on Nyon, the problem is your router. Could be, but I tried on at least 5 networks (that have no problem whatsoever). Could all 5 router producer be the problem? Not very likely ...

Comment: I have the same problem and I can't find a solution.
Seems that it's recognise the WPA or WPA2 but it not able to connect it.
Any suggestion are appreciated.
Thx
Franco

Comment: @Franco purely for troubleshooting can you set up an unsecured network?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to connect to an unsecured WLAN with my Nyon. I updated the Nyon and tried to connect to a secured network again, but no luck! I'll try to contact Bosch support about that problem too. I see following possible workaround's in the mean time:

1. If you only need to sync your cycling data, you can use the mobile app and connect via Bluetooth.
2. If possible with your WLAN router, enable an unsecured guest network and connect your Nyon to it. Switch off the guest network if you don't use it anymore.
3. Remove security from your WLAN while you need a connection from your Nyon. Don't forget to restore security settings, as soon you are done working with your Nyon!

Be aware that as long as you run a unsecured everybody within reach of your WLAN router can access your network and listen to the traffic on this network. Best stick with mobile app/bluetooth and use unsecured WLAN only to download maps or update the Nyon software.

Answer (score 3):

I have two Nyon computers and I can assure you they both connect to WPA and WPA2 secured networks.
BUT
this doesn't work reliably! Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Often it takes a dozen attempts (and password re-entries) or more (!) to finally establish a connection.
Have you tried to disable bluetooth on the unit? As bluetooth is using a similar frequency band, this sometimes helps.
Also, you need to be very, very close to the router as the Nyon has a bad reception. Believe me, the problem is not your router - it is the Nyon.

Comment: I will try. At the moment I had to create a special unprotected network that I switch on when I want to connect the Nyon.